# PostgreSQL Query precedence

Tags: postgresql

Here in the query when i am trying to execute the OR condition before AND conditions it gives wrong result..as web_filename_username_4hr_ts_201109 also gets included..
Wrong Result Query:

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
 WHERE schemaname = 'public'
   and (tablename like 'web%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'webs%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'webr%_4hr_ts_%'
        or tablename like '%web%summary%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'web_filename_username%_4hr_ts_%'
       )
     ;
```

But when i executed all AND before ORing it gives Correct result...
Correct Result Query:

```
SELECT tablename
  FROM pg_tables
 WHERE schemaname = 'public'
   and (tablename like 'web%_4hr_ts_%'
    and tablename not like 'webs%_12hr_ts_%'
    and tablename not like 'webr%_4hr_ts_%'
    and tablename not like 'web_filename_username%_4hr_ts_%'
     or tablename like '%web%summary%_4hr_ts_%'
       )
```

I dont know why....?????????

Comment: I edited your code a bit. AND and OR do not mix well.

Comment: why don't you try to add bracket "(" and ")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the way you have written it it checks in to blocks.

`tablename like 'web%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'webs%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'webr%_4hr_ts_%'`

or

`tablename like '%web%summary%_4hr_ts_%'
       and tablename not like 'web_filename_username%_4hr_ts_%'`

now obviously tablename can not match both `'%web%summary%_4hr_ts_%'` and `'web_filename_username%_4hr_ts_%'` so thats always going to be false.

Here is what explain says about it

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..28.55 rows=1 width=64)
   Join Filter: (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
   ->  Seq Scan on pg_class c  (cost=0.00..27.45 rows=1 width=72)
         Filter: ((relkind = 'r'::"char") AND (((relname ~~ 'web%_4hr_ts_%'::text) AND (relname !~~ 'webs%_4hr_ts_%'::text) AND (relname !~~ 'webr%_4hr_ts_%'::text)) OR ((relname ~~ '%web%summary%_4hr_ts_%'::text) AND (relname !~~ 'web_filename_username%_4hr_ts_%'::text))))
   ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace n  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=1 width=4)
         Filter: (n.nspname = 'public'::name)
```

As you can see its added brackets showing that the OR is at the top level. This is why when Im using any OR with AND I always use brackets to ensure the correct evaluation order.

If your ever wondering why a statement doesn't give you what you expect just stick explain in front of it and see what its going to do.

Comment: Table with [operator precedence for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE). As you can see, `AND` binds before `OR`. In case of doubt, add parentheses to overrule.

Answer (score 0):

Its' dependent on its order of execution, which is normally left to right.

You can over come this using brackets.